# Why are only certain plugins in zsh working while others aren't?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

This is my full .zshrc:

```
export ZSH="/Users/butters/.oh-my-zsh"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

plugins=(
    git
    bundler
    dotenv
    osx
    zake
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
    zsh-autosuggestions

)
```

It seems that only when `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is placed above the rest, my custom plugins work but all the other plugins such as osx stop working. When I placed it below the rest, osx works but zsh-syntax-highlighting and zsh-autosuggestions stop working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems in your setup:

- `plugins` is an array used by `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. You need to initialize the former *before* calling the latter. Just initializing `plugins` by itself doesn't do anything special in plain Zsh (apart from creating a plain old array).
- `zsh-syntax-highlighting` and `zsh-autosuggestions` mention explicitly in their documentation that they should be sourced *after* any other plugins.
- If you're going to manually `source` a plugin, then you do not need to add it to Oh-My-Zsh's `plugins` array.

So, therefore, for your setup, this is the correct way to do things:

```bash
ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh
plugins=(
    git
    bundler
    dotenv
    osx
    zake
)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
source /usr/local/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```